# generating images at runtime or not?

Tags: ios, optimization

ok..so i'm working on a game that requires quite a few layers so i was thinking of using images and lay them on top of each other but the problem is that i need 5 images per device (and i want to make the app universal) ...so that's 5x 4( iphone non-retina & retina, ipad retina & non-retina)

i made a few tests and the images are in average ~1.2 mb

counting that..and the splash screens the app will go over 25 mb easily (without any code .. or icons ... or anything)

the images are not too complicated so my question is : is it better to generate the images at runtime rather than having them in my app?

my main worry is that the app will be too slow...but on the other hand..the app will be 30 mb

edit: i decided to generate them when the app is loading the 1st time and save them to disk ...it will take a bit longer to load but its better for app size

Comment: Please post the sample images, I am fairly sure you could generate most all of what you need with CoreGraphics. This would be the best of both worlds, fast but with no need to package fat assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in the splash screen or the first few that are needed for your app to look fast the first time and generate and save the rest on the first run so that you have them available for the subsequent runs.

If your app is going to be larger than the 3G cap anyways why not put them in, if the rest of your app is going to be small its better to keep it small specially under the 3G cap (which is now 50Mb if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you will need to *measure* to answer your question definitively. "Not too complicated" is vague. There is not a hard/fast rule here.

Another angle would be to bundle the hi res artwork then resize them or generate the images, and then export them as files when the app is first launched (or even as dynamic intermediates).

"Too slow" is also not an easy measurement. Reading and potentially decompressing an image takes time. If the displayed size is variable, then you would also spend a good amount of time interpolating it on the fly, or compromising the quality. A resized image can suffer in quality or consume more memory than is required. Simply put, the problem cannot be simplified. If you want the "best" solution, you need to weigh and measure more than you have outlined in the OP, and determine what changes are worth your users' time.